# Errai RestEasy issue with 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: errai

I Am getting this error when running errai 3.0.0 SNAPSHOT
The same code works fine with 3.0.0.20130604-M1. Thanks

```
host].[/airit-mobile-demo].[com.airit.mobile.server.local.rest.RestApplication]]
 (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) JBWEB000235:
Allocate exception for servlet com.airit.mobile.server.local.rest.RestApplication:        java.lang.InstantiationException: org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:342) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.ja
va:146) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.
init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:67) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(
HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.
java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.jav
a:950) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:151) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmC
loserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-
4]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmC
loserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-
4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(Secu
rityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.
2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:92
0) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_43]
```

Comment: It looks like there should be a "Caused By:" clause with an InstantiationException after the stack trace you've provided above. Can you include the whole stack trace (including all nested causes) in the question?

Comment: In addition to the cause(s) of the exception above, it would also help to see the output of `mvn dependency:tree` on your project for both versions of Errai. Feel free to edit the question and add these details.